# Test aws-sdk-android-samples/AndroidPubSub but connection is refused

Tags: android, aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot

I was trying to test `aws-sdk-android-samples/AndroidPubSub/` from `https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub`, but after I clicked the connect, always get the error message

> a2k94wsqkar4rm-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/52.13.183.162 (port
>   8883) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection
>   refused)

I created my device certificate on the AWS IoT console and activated it, and also attached a policy described as below,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I tried two methods to install the certificate and key to the local key store, and both of them worked.

Method 1, by source code

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

// read cert and private key from pem file
InputStream input = assetManager.open("4ed2c76117-private.pem");
int size = input.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
input.read(buffer);
input.close();
String privateKeyPem = new String(buffer);
System.out.println(privateKeyPem);

input = assetManager.open("4ed2c76117-certificate.pem");
size = input.available();
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[size];
input.read(buffer2);
input.close();
String certPem = new String(buffer2);
System.out.println(certPem);

// store in keystore for use in MQTT client
// saved as alias "default" so a new certificate isn't
// generated each run of this application
AWSIotKeystoreHelper.saveCertificateAndPrivateKey(certificateId,
certPem,
privateKeyPem,
keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);

// load keystore from file into memory to pass on
// connection
clientKeyStore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.getIotKeystore(certificateId,
keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);
```

Method 2, by terminal command,

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out iot_keystore.p12 -inkey 4ed2c76117-private.pem -in 4ed2c76117-certificate.pem -name default

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore iot_keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore iot_keystore.bks -deststoretype bks --provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -–providerpath bcprov-jdk15on-164.jar

adb push iot_keystore.bks /data/user/0/com.amazonaws.demo.androidpubsub/files/iot_keystore
```

Can anyone help fix this issue?

Comment: i am unable to connect to aws iot thing. Backend guy has given some certificates. 
Firstly, isn't putting private certificates inside app bundle a bad thing? 
or do i need to create keystore from certicate and private key and using that i have to connect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think this is an emulator network issue. After connect the network correctly, this issue is gone.

Comment: Using the command to fix the network issue, C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_28 -dns-server 8.8.8.8